# How to build Chameleon bootloader from SVN source?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I'm trying to build the chameleon bootloader from the SVN source.  The project homepage can be found here, http://forge.voodooprojects.org/p/chameleon/

I checked out the source with the following command,

`svn co http://forge.voodooprojects.org/svn/chameleon`

I have tried, `make` `make all` `xcodebuild` but none of these seem to put a binary in the `build/Chameleon.build` directory.

*** Update ***

I'm trying to figure out how to build a binary such as the following,

http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~somlo/OSXKVM/chameleon_svn2360_boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed `make all` that builds the chameleon bootloader.  The `make help` command provided the necessary instructions needed.  And the bootloader file I needed for Qemu is located in the `trunk/sym/i386/boot`  I hope this help future visitors.